# tokenize a string into a string array WITHOUT using split method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, tokenize

how to tokenize a string into a string array without using split method in java?
for example:

```
input:    String abc ="dog cat bird fish";
output:   String[] def={"dog","cat","bird","fish"};
```

Comment: Why the odd requirement? This homework? We don't do homework...

Comment: Is this an assignment saying that you can't you the split method?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest with StringTokenizer:

```
String abc ="dog cat bird fish";
   StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(abc, " ");
   String[] def = new String[strTok.countTokens()];
   int count = 0;
   while(strTok.hasMoreTokens())
   {
       def[count++] = strTok.nextToken();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow is using Pattern api in java,

```
private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");
String[] arr = SPACE.split(str); // str is the string to be split
```

As an alternative to this you can use StringTokenizer.

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer("Hello I'm your String", " ");
String[] splited = new String[tokens.countTokens()];
int index = 0;
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
    splited[index] = tokens.nextToken();
    ++index;
}
```

You would write my own tokenizer - it may well end up being even more efficient than the more general purpose StringTokenizer which can look for multiple tokens, and you can make it behave however you'd like. For such a simple use case, it can be a simple implementation.

If it would be useful, you could even implement Iterable and get enhanced-for-loop support with strong typing instead of the Enumeration support provided by StringTokenizer. Let me know if you want any help coding such a beast up - it really shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

[`StringUtils#split`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) from Apache commons-lang3 does not use `split` directly on a string, although the operations of splitting are somewhat similar to `split` function, but without using regexes.

Here's the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java#StringUtils.split%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) for reference